# Creating an empty flashable zip

Tags: android, zip

I have created flashable zip. But it has empty folders in it. For example it has system/media and nothing in it. It only has one apk in data/app. And when I flash it, it gives me an error:

```
E:Error executing updater binary in zip
```

Is this because of empty folders or something else?? I am using TWRP and even tried different updater-binaries but nothing seems to work.

this is my updater-script

```
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/data");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");
package_extract_dir("data", "/data");
unmount("/data");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "unmount", "/data");
unmount("/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "unmount", "/system");
```